# pcb2gcode fails install in Arch due to gerbv version not being detected

Tags: manjaro, g-code

I'm attempting install of pcb2gcode on Manjaro Arch. I have tried every PKGBUILD file I can find online, and nothing is working for me. I've explicitly installed multiple versions of gerbv package to try to fulfil the dependency, and rerun the pcb2gcode install each time...  Every single time, I get the same output:

```
checking for glibmm... yes

checking for gdkmm... yes

checking for gerbv... no

configure: error: Package requirements (libgerbv >= 2.1.0) were not met:

Package dependency requirement 'libgerbv >= 2.1.0' could not be satisfied.

Package 'libgerbv' has version '', required version is '>= 2.1.0'

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables gerbv_CFLAGS
and gerbv_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.

See the pkg-config man page for more details.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

At the time of this output, gerbv version 2.8.1 was installed, well above 2.1.0

I see that there are possible workarounds suggested (I assume these mean using ./configure to set the apparently unknown gerbv path, or environment variables that skip the version check altogether), but I just don't know how to implement them. Even if I did know how to set these variables... I don't know what value they should be set to.

Answer (score 3):

This is my valid file before update:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include
pkgincludedir=${prefix}/include/gerbv-

Name: libgerbv
Description: Core library for gerbv
Requires: glib-2.0 gtk+-2.0
Version:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgerbv
Cflags: -I${pkgincludedir}
```

and after update:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include
pkgincludedir=${prefix}/include/gerbv-

Name: libgerbv
Description: Core library for gerbv
Requires: glib-2.0 gtk+-2.0
Version: 2.7
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgerbv
Cflags: -I${pkgincludedir}
```

Just wrote **'2.7'** after ***'Version:'***

Comment: This worked for me on a Mint install which didn't want to play.  Note that the file in question is libgerbv.pc, on my machine it's in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/` (not being Arch & all)

Comment: terminal command 'locale libgerbv' do not work?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your installed version by entering:

```bash
sudo pamac search gerb
```

Then edit the file `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libgerbv.pc` and add the version number  line `Version:` which in this case is blank.

I had the same problem trying to install `pcb2gcode` and this fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe you can improve this answer by adding an example of valid contents for the `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libgerbv.pc` file. Thanks for contributing